# Find the Nth term of series

Tags: algorithm, math

While solving a problem, i came across the following sequence:

```
 3, 9, 21, 46, 94, 185, 353...
```

We have to find the nth term of the sequence .

```
Answer should have complexity of O(1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the meta-algorithm for this kind of question. First, look up the sequence on OEIS:

http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+9%2C+21%2C+46%2C+94%2C+185%2C+353&language=english&go=Search

Look at the Formula section and find

```
a(n) = n*F(n+2)-F(n+3)+2,
```

where `F` is the Fibonacci function. Evaluate this formula in O(log n) arithmetic operations with a [fast Fibonacci implementation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975741/applying-fibonacci-fast-doubling-identities).

O(1) is infeasible in sensible machine models.

Comment: Since each Fibonacci number can be expressed as a multiple of the sum of two powers of `n` this can be done in O(1), at least if you consider the operation `x**y` (or `x^y`) to be O(1). If you do that exponentation with `exp()` and `log()` it basically is O(1).